# Link error when compiling WIN32 application with CLion/CMake/MSVC 2015

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, cmake, clion

I am unable to compile a simple WIN32 application using CLion with Visual Studio 2015 as a toolchain. Here is the linker error I am getting:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable test-test.exe
MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
test-test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
LINK Pass 1 failed. with 1120
```

Below is the most simplified version of the code that reproduce the issue. It is contain in these two files:

- CMakeList.txt

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.6)
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 main.cpp)
  ```
- main.cpp

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      std::cout << "HELLO WORLD!" << std::endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

More details on the tools I am using:

- CLION 2018.1 EAP (latest version)

  - I also tested with previous non EAP versions, with the same results
  - CLion's toolchain architecture is set to x86_amd64
  - CLion's CMake build type is set to Debug
- CMake 3.9.6
- Visual Studio 2015 (Community)

Please advise

**EDIT 1**

As I mentioned, I simplified the code as much as possible to reproduce the error. Thus, using a std::out. The real application is in fact a QT application, not a console application.

I am adding the WIN32 argument in the CMakeList.txt file for the application to start directly the GUI when executing the EXE (instead of loading a command line prompt and then load the GUI).

Comment: Lose the WIN32 entry in the cmake file. Also, why use CLion with VS? Why not just use VS?

Comment: You have to define `WinMain` instead of `main` is convenient for `console`.

Comment: "Here is the compile error I am getting" - no. That's not a compiler error you are getting, "error LNK2019: ..." Is a *linker* error. Different thing - the compiler has no problem with your code here, but the linker does.

Comment: @Raindrop - no, you do not need to define WinMai for a console application.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Good point. I edited it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I develop in Java, PHP and C++. Jetbrains provides a IDE feature consistency in IDE for these three languages. Plus, I am not a big fan of Visual Studio as an IDE.

Comment: OK, then why don't you use GCC  with CLion instead of MSVC++?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: But the OP said `Win32` application not just a Console one?.

Comment: @Raindrop The code he posted appears to be that of a console application.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Ok thank you.

Comment: The linker's /SUBSYSTEM option matters.  If you don't target the Console sub-system then the expected entrypoint name is WinMain instead of main.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is to be expected. It just follows documented behavior for the line

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 main.cpp)
```

From [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html):

> If `WIN32` is given the property [WIN32_EXECUTABLE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html#prop_tgt:WIN32_EXECUTABLE) will be set on the target created. See documentation of that target property for details.

The documentation for [WIN32_EXECUTABLE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html#prop_tgt:WIN32_EXECUTABLE):

> [...] When this property is set to true the executable when linked on Windows will be created with a WinMain() entry point instead of just main(). [...]

You have 2 options:

- Remove the `WIN32` from the `add_executable` command.
- Replace `int main(int, char**)` with the [WinMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559.aspx) entry point: `int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)`.

The second option is likely what you are looking for, if you do not want a console window to pop up.

Answer (score 2):

[IInspectable's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48925785/577603) covered this pretty well, but I have one small addition.

Since you wrote that you are using a Qt application: [Qt offers a mechanism](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#qtmain-lib-on-windows) for handling this problem in a portable way.

Qt ships with a static library `qtmain.lib` which defines a `WinMain()` function for you that simply forwards all command line arguments to the `main` function (which, in case of a Win32 executable, is just an ordinary function). For Qt5, you can simply add the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if(WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Qt5::WinMain)
endif()
```

Note that this will only work if Qt5 was already found correctly by an earlier `find_package` call.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Add linking to Qt5::WinMain fixed my issue my QT application.

Comment: This makes the code more portable than explicitly writing a `WinMain()`.  Nice job!